# how does と～と～による work?

Tags: grammar, manga

[image]

I know the individual words but I'm not familiar with the form used in the left bubble so I am not sure what she is trying to convey.

context: they were talking about something else, and a cat passed by. The brown hair girl glared at it then we get this panel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a grammar point. と is simply acting conjunctively to link nouns while による here means "depending on". Here is how the sentence is parsed:

> （時と場合と猫）による 
> It depends on the time, the situation, and the cat.

Comment: ahh got it. didn't think about it this way, thanks

Comment: Since it wasn't mentioned in the question, it's maybe worth mentioning that 時と場合による is something of a set phrase.

Comment: @earthlin, i didnt know that. I will make sure to commit it to memory. Thank you.